# jQuery e.preventdefault() - Redirect not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**jQuery Snippet:**

```
$("#btn_milestone_submit").click(function (e) {
            var milestone_id= $("#btn_milestone_submit" + <?php echo $getMilestoneDetails[$i]['MILESTONE_ID']; ?>).val();
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.href="myController/myAction?milestone_id="+milestone_id;
    });
```

Here `milestone_id` value is being passed to `myAction` but redirection is not working. It does not reach the function.

```
function myAction(){
    echo 'Action called';
}
```

Removing `e.preventDefault()`, prevents redirection and reloads the page again. How do I redirect to `myAction` when clicked on submit button ?

Comment: If you show your html we can be sure, but I have the feeling you have several `#btn_milestone_submit` buttons. If this is correct, change it to a button with a class (`.btn_milestone_submit`).

Comment: @giorgio The fact that the `e.preventDefault()` works (in the sense that it prevents form submission) suggests that the event handler code is executing, so the current ID selector is possibly correct.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist that doesn't really makes sense... I have seen before that only the first element with an ID selector will be selected by jQuery. Removing the e.preventDefault() shouldn't execute the code that comes after it (in this case the `window.location.href`), but it might follow a link, if the element is an anchor element (eg. `<a href="#"/>`. Anyway, this is all merely speculation as we have too little info from the OP ;)

Comment: btw: @krishna shah, where exactly is the `myAction()` function being called?

Comment: Don't use `e.preventDefault()` if you want to redirect that.

Answer (score -1):

Using only `myController/myAction?milestone_id=` may cause problems when you are not in the site root page.

You can do a relative redirect depending on the level which you want to redirect to:

```
window.location.href = '/myController/myAction?milestone_id='; //relative to domain
```